# Is the Euclidean generating functional $Z_{E}[J]$ identified with original Minkowskian generating functional $Z[J]$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, wick-rotation

In quantum field theory, it is common to perform wick rotation $t\rightarrow -i\tau$ and get Euclidean generating functional $Z_{E}[J]$. When I first studied QFT, I just saw this a magic trick to simplify calculation. More formally (but hand-waving), I thought we just see the real time parameter $t$ extending to the whole complex plane, then we perform contour integral and identify value which is obtained from integration in real time $t$ with the value from integration in imaginary time $t$. Then we extract real parameter $\tau=it$. In the end, we have generating functional $$Z_{E}[J]=\int \mathscr{D}\phi e^{-S_{E}[\phi]/\hbar}.$$ However, I am confused whether this Euclidean generating functional is same as Minkowskian counterpart $$Z[J]=\int \mathscr{D}\phi e^{iS[\phi]/\hbar}.$$ From Cauchy theorem, they seem the same. However, $Z$ can be complex but $Z_{E}$ seems always real due to its form. A good example is the free-particle system.

One the other hand, if they are not identified, how could we use semi-classic methods such as instantons to evaluate amplitudes?

Comment: More on [Wick rotation between QFT and stat mech](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wick-rotation+quantum-field-theory+statistical-mechanics).

Comment: There is just obscene amounts of literature on this Wick rotation business. It is definitely fascinating, and you are definitely correct to be interested in it, but you should just read up. In short, the answer is yes, but you cannot do simple approximations. If you do it too simply, then you will lose too much information to reconstruct the Minkowskian functional you want.